# Derive Cramer-Rao lower bound for $Var(\hat{\theta})$ given that $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}U]=1$

Tags: statistics, expected-value, statistical-inference, variance, fisher-information

I am trying to derive the Cramer-Rao lower bound for $Var(\hat{\theta})$ given that we already know $\mathbb{E}[U]=0$, $Var(U)=I(\theta)$ and $\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}U]=1$. I am struggling with using the last fact, I know that the CRLB will be equal to $1/I(\theta)$ but can’t figure out how to use what is given to find this, any help would be much appreciated.